# What is the USB Rubber Ducky escape character for " (double quote)?

Tags: duckyscript

I have a script like this:

```
REM *** Define DUCKY drive as %duck%
STRING for /f %d in ('wmic volume get driveletter^, label ^| findstr "DUCKY"') 
do set duck=%d
ENTER
```

with more code (which isn't important for now) saved to the USB Rubber Ducky. But when it runs, command prompt reads it as:

```
for /f %d in ('wmic volume get driveletter^, label ^| findstr @DUCKY@') do 
set duck=%d
```

with @DUCKY@ instead of "DUCKY". How can I escape the double quotes ("") character?

Comment: In this case, the quotes are superfluous. The utility `findstr` will accept a non-quoted string as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the quotes are superfluous. The utility `findstr` will accept a non-quoted string as a parameter. Thanks @[Goodies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3124409/goodies)

Answer (score 1):

while the Findstr will accept a non-quoted string, I believe you can use the `\"` as an escape character. It seems to work on BashBunny.

FYI I just posted on the forums a way to grab USB drive letter and assign it to `%DRIVE%` and use it to call something off the USB.